# Correct way to configure connection between Teradata and python on Linux RHEL

Tags: python, linux, database, teradata, rhel

I installed teradata module for python2.7, the teradata client 15.00, also set the environment variables ODBCINI, ODBCINST and LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly. But when I create my connection in my py script:

```
odbclib="/opt/teradata/client/15.00/odbc_64/lib/libodbc.so"
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="terapp", version="1.0", logConsole=True, odbcLibPath=odbclib)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="XXX.XX.XX.XX",username=user, password=pass)
```

I got this:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/teradata/udaexec.py", line 183, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 374, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 206, in checkStatus
 teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, u'[IM003] [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded')
```

Please, any help clever people

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RHEL?  This is only a guess, but if it's RHEL 6, Python 2.7 is not installed by default so install Python 2.7 via Software Collections (part of most subscription).  See http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started-rhel6-python/ and install python27 version.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it's a Linux version 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-ol6-builder-05) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) and python version installed is 2.7.12